# Div follows vertical scroll

Tags: css

I have a div. I want when user scroll the page vertically this div follows the movement and stay at the center of the screen.

Is there any css command for this, or something else?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `position:fixed`?

Comment: you must describe **exactly** what you need and I mean **exactly**, because this could have so many different scenarios.

Comment: I want the div follows the vertical scroll, but not the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You can position it using `position:fixed;`

Given a div of width 400px and height 400px:

```
div#center
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; /*move top-left corner to center*/
    left: 50%;

    margin-left: -200px; /* (-1) * (width/2), move left by 1/2 of the width*/
    margin-top: -200px; /* (-1) * (height/2), move up by 1/2 of the height*/

    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: However, if i put position:fixed the div will also follows the horizontal scroll. I want to do it only for the vertical scroll.

Comment: @xarlap I can't think of a purely-CSS way to do that. You'll need some javascript in there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `position: fixed;` will work if I understand your question correctly.

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
        position: fixed; top:50%; left:50%;
        height: 200px; width: 200px;
        margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -100px;
    }
```

Here is a link to work Codepen of a working example: [**CODEPEN LINK**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYPoGV)

As I am posting this it seems that @MathNerdProductions has given a pretty similar answer, take your pick really. They both do the same thing, you should credit them with the answer as they answered first.